# If entity exists in array, showing add or remove button

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have entities **Travel** , **Favorite** and **User** , each user can add a travel to his list of favorites.

When display list of all travels, I'd like that if travel is already in lis of user favorites so show button (remove) and if is not in list, so show (add to favorite).

In the action controller I have done a queryBuilder to get list of all favorites of current authenticated user and I put the result in **($favorite)**.

```
    public function listAction($page, Request $request)
    {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    // code of boutton add to or remove from favorite
    $user = $this->getUser(); // this is a function to verify if user is AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED
    if($user) {
    $favorite = $em->getRepository('ProjectTravelBundle:Favorite')->getFavoriteByUser($user);
    }
    else{
    $favorite = '';
    }

    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');

    $qb = $em->getRepository('ProjectTravelBundle:Travel')->getListTravelsFrontend();
    $nb = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $qb,
        $request->query->get('page', $page),10);


    return $this->render('ProjectFrontendBundle:Travel:travel-list-view.html.twig',array(
        'pagination' => $pagination,
        'nb' => $nb,
        'favorite' =>$favorite, // list of favorites of current user 
    ));
}
```

The solution that I think about is to test if travel is **in array(favorite)** so show boutton remove and if not, then show boutton add , but I failed to do this in the **show.twig**

```
{% for travel in pagination %}
//..................

{% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') %}

{% if travel.id not in favorite %}
    <span><a href="{{ path('frontend_travel_add_favorite', {'id': travel.id} ) }}" class="pull-right button btn-small red">Add to favorite</a></span>
{% else %}
    <span><a href="{{ path('frontend_travel_delete_favorite', {'id': favorite.id} ) }}" class="pull-right button btn-small red">Remove from</a></span>
{% endif %}

// if user is not AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED
{% else %}
<span><a href="{{ path('frontend_travel_add_favorite', {'id': travel.id} ) }}" class="pull-right button btn-small red">Add to favorite</a></span>
{% endif %}

//..........
{% endfor %}
```

**Repository: queryBuilder**

```
    // get list of favorite of current user
    public function getFavoriteByUser($user)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('f')
            ->Where('f.user = '.$user);

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

**UPDATED**

**FavoriteEntity**

```
class Favorite
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project\UserBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
protected $user;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project\TravelBundle\Entity\Travel", inversedBy="favorites")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
protected $travel;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set user
 *
 * @param \Project\UserBundle\Entity\User $user
 * @return Favorite
 */
public function setUser(\Project\UserBundle\Entity\User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get user
 *
 * @return \Project\UserBundle\Entity\User 
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}


/**
 * Set travel
 *
 * @param \Project\TravelBundle\Entity\Travel $travel
 * @return Favorite
 */
public function setTravel(\Project\TravelBundle\Entity\Travel $travel)
{
    $this->travel = $travel;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get travel
 *
 * @return \Project\TravelBundle\Entity\Travel 
 */
public function getTravel()
{
    return $this->travel;
}
}
```

**TravelEntity**

```
class Travel
{
/....

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Project\TravelBundle\Entity\Favorite", mappedBy="travel", cascade={"remove"})
 */
private $favorites; 


public function __construct()
{
    $this->favorites = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/...........
/**
 * Add favorites
 *
 * @param \Project\TravelBundle\Entity\Favorite $favorites
 * @return Travel
 */
public function addFavorite(\Project\TravelBundle\Entity\Favorite $favorites)
{
    $this->favorites[] = $favorites;
    $favorites->setTravel($this);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove favorites
 *
 * @param \Project\TravelBundle\Entity\Favorite $favorites
 */
public function removeFavorite(\Project\TravelBundle\Entity\Favorite $favorites)
{
    $this->favorites->removeElement($favorites);
}

/**
 * Get favorites
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getFavorites()
{
    return $this->favorites;
}
```

Comment: Show you `Favorite` entity, please

Comment: I have updated my question, you can see entities now

Comment: I also suggest you to remove `$favorites` OneToMany relationship from TravelEntity. Such relationships may consume a lot of resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could try this:

In your controller:

```
if($user) {
    $favorite = $em->getRepository('ProjectTravelBundle:Favorite')->getFavoriteByUser($user);
    $ids = array_map(function($entity) { return $entity->getTravel()->getId(); }, $favorite);
} else{
    $favorite = '';
    $ids = array();
}
...
return $this->render('ProjectFrontendBundle:Travel:travel-list-view.html.twig',array(
        'ids' => $ids,
        'pagination' => $pagination,
        'nb' => $nb,
        'favorite' =>$favorite, // list of favorites of current user 
    ));
```

In your template:

```
{% if travel.id not in ids %}
    <span><a href="{{ path('frontend_travel_add_favorite', {'id': travel.id} ) }}" class="pull-right button btn-small red">Add to favorite</a></span>
{% else %}
    <span><a href="{{ path('frontend_travel_delete_favorite', {'id': favorite.id} ) }}" class="pull-right button btn-small red">Remove from</a></span>
{% endif %}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, it should work, but if you replace `$favorite->map(function($entity) { return $entity->getId(); })->toArray();` with `$favorite->map(function($entity) { return $entity->getTravel()->getId(); })->toArray();`. That is why i asked about entities code

Comment: @Ziumin Thanks for the tip, I've updated the answer. Hope it works now.

Comment: @hous please check if it works now, as Ziumin said, it was impossible to know how to access the correct data without entity info.

Comment: I get this errror `Error: Call to a member function map() on a non-object`

Comment: @hous my mistake, the getResult() always returns an array. I think it'll work now.

Comment: thank you, now I don't have no error is displayed but it doesn't work. I have changed `$ids = array_map(function($entity) { $entity->getTravel()->getId(); }, $favorite);` by this code `$ids = array(1,2,3);` to test what it gives , it work very well

Comment: @hous I've updated the answer. Try `$ids = array_map(function($entity) { return $entity->getTravel()->getId(); }, $favorite);` I forgot to put the return statement within the closure. I hope this time works